# How to get readable Data::Printer output inside neovim?

Tags: ansi-escape

I'm not sure what I need to tweak here. When I exec my Perl file from within `neovim` I get unreadable output. I'm using `Data::Printer` 1.000004

```
nvim --version
NVIM v0.7.0-dev+1135-gfdea15723
```

```
cat ~/.dataprinter
array_max = 5000
end_separator = 1
filters = DB, DateTime, JSON, URI
hash_separator = ' => '
index = 1
scalar_quotes = '
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( state );
use List::SomeUtils qw( part );

my $i = 0;
my @part = part { $i++ % 2 } 1 .. 8;

use DDP;
p @part;
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~

:call ExecFile()
:!"/Users/olafalders/Documents/perl/part.pl"
^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m[^[[0m
    ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[0] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m[^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[0] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m1^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[1] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m3^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[2] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m5^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[3] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m7^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
        ^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m]^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
    ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[1] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m[^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[0] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m2^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[1] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m4^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[2] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m6^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
            ^[[0;38;2;161;187;197m[3] ^[[0m^[[0;38;2;247;140;106m8^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
        ^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m]^[[0m^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m,^[[0m
^[[0;38;2;102;217;239m]^[[0m
```

The actual output should look like:

```
[
    [0] [
            [0] 1,
            [1] 3,
            [2] 5,
            [3] 7,
        ],
    [1] [
            [0] 2,
            [1] 4,
            [2] 6,
            [3] 8,
        ],
]
```

Comment: Neovim is not Vim. You must use :terminal command instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data::Printer` describes itself as:

> colored & full-featured pretty print of Perl data structures and objects

The garbage you see is the escape sequences used by the package to colorise the output, which is not understood by the shell in which the script is executed.

To solve your problem at the script/environment level, I'd suggest reading [the documentation of the package](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer#Colors-&-Themes), which mentions a `colored` property and a `ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED` environment variable. It should have been your first move.

To solve it at the editor level, I'd suggest using the built-in `:help :terminal`, which supports ANSI colours, instead of `:!`, which doesn't.

And, by the way, the quickfix window is not involved, here.